# executing a script via php exec which creates a file on the server

Tags: php, bash, shell, exec

I have a php script which calls a shell script as below -

```
#!/bin/bash
timestamp=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S")
echo $timestamp >> results
```

The php script -

```
<?php

$mycmd = exec('/bin/bash exectest.sh',$op,$er);
var_dump($mycmd);
var_dump($op);
echo $er."\n";

?>
```

The php script returns error code 1 for $er but when i tried to modify the shell script to just print instead of writing to a file. the Php script then returns 0 and succeeds.

Any ideas of where I need to fix this?
I have tried giving the full path for the script and also this is the same case when i tried using a python script in place of a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation indicates that this is most likely a permission problem, e.g. the user running PHP does not have write permission to either the `results` file in its current working directory or the directory itself (if the file does not exist yet).

Answer (score 0):

It happened to be running on an AFS machine hence required afs priviledges for httpd.

```
fs sa . http write
```

sorted the issue.